# Wifi-Lan Port blocking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tcp, tcpip

I'm writing a paired (windows) server and (android) client application suite that uses TCP connections over wifi on a funny port number. The Server advertises its availability using Bonjour/Zeroconf.

It works great on my development lan. But rarely anywhere else.

So on a lark I had the server create its own wifi hostednetwork. And it always works so far everywhere I've tried it.

I'm not trying to go out to the internet. The app doesn't need internet access in the slightest. My install program also tells Windows Firewall about its needs.

Is it wrong of me to expect that in most wifi configurations, just on the WLAN side, a port in the low 4 digits to not be blocked?

If so, what ports can I expect to not be blocked? I'm willing to run on port 80 if I must. I'd just like to co-exist with a web server if the machine already has one.

Comment: I think it's wrong to expect a Windows server to even have WLAN.

Comment: I always use 5 digit port numbers for random custom things, to avoid conflicts. Why do you think low 4 digit numbers are better choice?

Comment: My App Requires a WLAN card, and I programatically create a hostednetwork so that's not a problem. It's a server app, but it's not a server in the "fileserver" or "mailserver" sense. It's going to be running on a desktop or laptop to talk to the android clients which obviously will have wifi capability.

Comment: I chose a particular port number because the number had some significance to people who use the app. Like 1861 would for a Civil War Buff. Are higher number ports more likely to work?

Comment: While it is now common *in a home environment* for wifi connected devices to be able to "see" each other it is not generally preferred in a commercial situation due to the generally untrusted and random nature of the connected devices. It is insecure and potentially exposes a lot of devices to other devices that may have malware infection.  It was not that long ago that even on home networks the wired and wireless networks were isolated from each other.

Comment: Okay then. Creating its own wifi network is going to become part of the standard operating procedure. It will save time configuring the client devices too. I got surprised that a fios router defaulted to my app failing to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends quite a lot on your environment. I would imagine that in most SOHO-environments, this would work, regardless of the port number you use.

In large corporations however, the WiFi network is often a central solution and there will, in general, be firewalls between your windows server and your WiFi network. Most of the time, different clients on WiFi are not even able to see each other, so your bonjour would not even work.

Anything between SOHO and large corporate networks, it depends on the network administrator's knowledge and his sense of security.

Comment: The target environment is the random wifi you'd find in a community center or restaurant. 

Bonjour seems to always work. But even on a Verizon FIOS router, at a friends house, I couldn't connect to the server on the IP/Port being advertised over Bonjour. The Server happened to have some VMWare Virtual Devices the service bound to if that matters. The server is provided by IIS running on a funny port. On my wifi (not provided by my ISP's router, but my own) it's no problem at all. I just want a way to confirm or deny what the issue is.